# set a log to min and max level, as to exclude errors

Tags: python, python-2.7

let's say I wanted to have several handlers, but I did not want the `logging.ERROR` level messages to show up in any file except `logs/error.log`

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/debug.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=1)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

error_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/error.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=1)
error_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

app.logger.addHandler(handler)
app.logger.addHandler(error_handler)
```

so let's say I wanted handler to handle everything from `logging.DEBUG` up to and including `logging.WARNING`, but NOT including `logging.ERROR`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a custom [logging filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects) to filter out records with a level you don't need:

```
class LevelFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, level):
        self.level = level

    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno != self.level
```

Then you can add the filter to the handler using [`addFilter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.addFilter):

```
handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/debug.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=1)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.addFilter(LevelFilter(logging.ERROR))
```

In this case, you wouldn't see messages with `ERROR` level in `debug.log`.

Also see:

- [python logging specific level only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162419/python-logging-specific-level-only)
- [What is the point of setLevel in a python logging handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668633/what-is-the-point-of-setlevel-in-a-python-logging-handler)

Hope this is what you need.