# logging module - Reducing the handler to exactly one level

Tags: python, logging

I know that if I set the level to e.g. `logging.DEBUG` it will dump everything up to *critical*. But I want to capture exactly only *debug* messages. Is this possible? I already read this article:

[python logging specific level only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162419/python-logging-specific-level-only)

But I don't get it. Adding filters like `handler1.addFilter(MyFilter(logging.DEBUG))` or using `IsEnabledFor()` hasn't worked. :(

I hope, you can help me.

Comment: Could you provide your code snippet please.

Comment: Yes, please provide a bit more context here, next time (the code, the expectation and what exactly went wrong). I found this question interesting, so I played a bit with the filter and provided it as an answer. I hope it solves your problem, but it is more a guess, because you haven't provided much information and we cannot see where you actually didn't understand something.

Comment: @colidyre : Thank you for your efforts and your hints concerning open threads. I will mark the open posts as "solved". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code example from given url shows `return logRecord.levelno <= self.__level`. I think, you need a `==` for your use case (or to allow only one level to be more exact, i.e. also works for info level only):

```py
import logging

# A simple formatting configuration with output to a file
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s :: %(name)s :: %(levelname)s :: %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", filename="output.log", filemode="a",
    level=logging.DEBUG  # allow everything and filter later
)

logger = logging.getLogger(name="Filtered")


class MyFilter:
    def __init__(self, level):
        self.__level = level

    def filter(self, logRecord):
        return logRecord.levelno == self.__level


logger.debug("This should be written (before applying filter)")
logger.info("This should be written (before applying filter)")
logger.warning("This should be written (before applying filter)")
logger.error("This should be written (before applying filter)")
logger.critical("This should be written (before applying filter)")

logger.addFilter(MyFilter(logging.INFO))

logger.debug("This should not be written, because levelno != debug")
logger.info("This should be written, because levelno == info")  # <--- !
logger.warning("This should not be written, because levelno != warning")
logger.error("This should not be written, because levelno != error")
logger.critical("This should not be written, because levelno != critical")
```

outputs as configured to file `output.log` with this content:

```
2023-07-04 20:21:10 :: Filtered :: DEBUG :: This should be written (before applying filter)
2023-07-04 20:21:10 :: Filtered :: INFO :: This should be written (before applying filter)
2023-07-04 20:21:10 :: Filtered :: WARNING :: This should be written (before applying filter)
2023-07-04 20:21:10 :: Filtered :: ERROR :: This should be written (before applying filter)
2023-07-04 20:21:10 :: Filtered :: CRITICAL :: This should be written (before applying filter)
2023-07-04 20:21:10 :: Filtered :: INFO :: This should be written, because levelno == info
```

In your case it will be `logger.addFilter(MyFilter(logging.DEBUG))` of course.